# Deeplearning4j parsing model into a DataSet

Tags: java, android, csv, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

The official guides for Deeplearning4j show how to use .csv files, but I want to know how to use my custom models with it. I tried looking for an appropriate DataSet implementation but can't seem to find any. Even if it would take the contents (in string format) of a normal .csv it would be good enough. I tried doing it like this:

Model:

```
package com.example.kamil.deeplearningandroid;

public class Job implements LearnableModel {
private int type;
private int salary;
private int choice;

public Job(String type, int salary, boolean choice) {
    this.type = encodeType(type);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.choice = encodeChoice(choice);
}

private int encodeType(String job) {
    switch (job) {
        case "Mechanic": return 0;
        case "Programmer": return 1;
        case "Teacher": return 2;
        case "Driver": return 3;
        case "Cook": return 4;
        default: return 5;
    }
}

private int encodeChoice(boolean choice) {
    return choice ? 1: 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return type + SEPARATOR + salary + SEPARATOR + choice + "\n";
}
}
```

and in JobClassifier:

```
 private DataSet readStringDataset(List<LearnableModel> data, int batchSize, int labelIndex, int numClasses) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    RecordReader rr = new LineRecordReader();
    rr.initialize(new StringSplit(modelToString(data)));
    DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(rr,batchSize,labelIndex,numClasses);
    return iterator.next();
}

private String modelToString(List<LearnableModel> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (LearnableModel model: list) {
        sb.append(model.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

With all this I'm getting:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1,10,0
W/System.err: 1,15,1
W/System.err: 4,7,0
W/System.err: 5,10,1
W/System.err: 3,10,0
W/System.err: 3,20,0
W/System.err: 4,5,0
W/System.err: 4,12,1
W/System.err: 2,20,1
W/System.err: 2,4,0
W/System.err: 5,12,1
W/System.err: 0,10,0
W/System.err: 5,5,0
W/System.err: 1,10,0
W/System.err: 2,16,1
W/System.err: 3,30,1
W/System.err: 4,16,1
W/System.err: 5,19,1
W/System.err: 5,6,0
W/System.err: 1,11,0"
W/System.err:     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
W/System.err:     at org.datavec.api.writable.Text.toDouble(Text.java:601)
W/System.err:     at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.getDataSet(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:271)
W/System.err:     at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:177)
W/System.err:     at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:372)
W/System.err:     at org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:52)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kamil.deeplearningandroid.JobClassifier.readStringDataset(JobClassifier.java:185)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kamil.deeplearningandroid.JobClassifier.classify(JobClassifier.java:65)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kamil.deeplearningandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use [datavec](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec). There's not "data set implementation" Everything gets converted to ndarrays.

Our examples more than cover this: http://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples

Edit: for inference on a simple csv. You can do a simple:
String[] arr = line.split(",");

Create a double[] or float[] via Float.parseFloat and Double.parseDouble()

and then do:
INDArray arr = Nd4j.create(float[]); or INDArray arr = Nd4j.create(double[]);

You don't need a dataset for inference/scoring, only for training which you would then use datavec with a RecordReaderDataSetIterator or SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator for time series.

Comment: Both links are nonoperational at the moment. You likely meant https://deeplearning4j.org/datavecdoc/ and http://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples